# ember router v2 goBack functionality

Tags: ember.js

In router V1 you can make a simple goBack functionality like this:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        redirectsTo: 'posts'
    }),
    posts: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/posts',
        showPost: Ember.Route.transitionTo('post'),
        connectOutlets: function(router){
           router.get('applicationController').
               connectOutlet('posts',App.Post.find());
        }
    }),
    post: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/posts/:post_id',
        goBack: Ember.Route.transitionTo('posts'),
        connectOutlets: function(router, post) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('post', post);
        }
    })
  })
});
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in router v2 and came up with the following solution:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathDidChange: function () {
    this.set('_previousPath', this.get('_currentPath'));
    this.set('_currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
  }.observes('currentPath')
});

App.GobackRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function (model) {
    var previousPath = this.controllerFor('application').get('_previousPath');

    var parts = previousPath.split(".");

    var router = this.get('router');
    if (router.hasRoute(parts[parts.length - 1])) {
        this.transitionTo(parts[parts.length - 1]);
    } else if (router.hasRoute(parts[parts.length - 2] + "." + parts[parts.length - 1])) {
        this.transitionTo(parts[parts.length - 2] + "." + parts[parts.length - 1]);
    } else {
        Ember.Logger.warn('No route for: %s', previousPath);
    }
  }
});
```

Isn't there a much simpler solution to this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEmMM/7/)

I would like to reuse the routes, controllers, etc... without resulting in some sort of spaghetti routing like

```
App.AnimalsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    goBackToThis: function() {
        this.transitionTo('this');
    },
    goBackToThat: function() {
        this.transitionTo('that');
    },
    goBackToSomeThingElse: function() {
        this.transitionTo('someThingElse');
    }
  } 
});
```

I would like to have 1 goback functionality for the whole router!
My initial solution result in something like the following: (look for all the goBack routes, and the reuse of the ebed routes)

```
App.Router.map(function (match) {
    this.route('home', { path: '/' });
    this.route('logout');
    this.route('login');
    this.resource('goBack', { path: '/goback' });

    this.resource('ccpr', function () {
        this.resource('goBack', { path: '/goback' });
        this.resource('ccprPatients',  { path: '/' }, function () {
            this.route('search');
        });
        this.resource('ccprPatient', { path: '/:ccpr_patient_id' }, function () {
            this.resource('goBack', { path: '/goback' });       
            this.resource('ccprPracticeSessions', { path: '/practicesessions' }, function () {
            });
            this.resource('ccprPracticeSession', { path: '/practicesessions/:ccpr_practicesession_id' }, function () {
                this.route('info');
                this.route('anamnese');
                this.route('medication');
                this.route('trainingModel', { path: '/trainingmodel' });
                this.route('socialEvaluation', { path: '/socialevaluation' });
                this.route('medicalFollowUp', { path: '/medicalfollowup' });
                this.route('psychologicalEvaluation', { path: '/psychologicalevaluation' });
                this.route('nutritionalAdvice', { path: '/nutritionaladvice' });

                this.resource('goBack', { path: '/goback' });

                this.resource('ebedMedication', { path: '/ebedmedication/:ebed_medication_id' }, function () {
                });
                this.resource('ebedLabResult', { path: '/ebedlabresult/:ebed_labresult_id' }, function () {
                });
                this.resource('ebedDietContact', { path: '/ebeddietcontact/:ebed_dietcontact_id' }, function () {
                });
                this.resource('ebedNutritionBmi', { path: '/ebednutritionbmi/:ebed_nutritionbmi_pkid' }, function () {
                });
            });
        });
        this.resource('ccprCardioArticles', { path: "/cardioarticles" });
        this.resource('ccprCardiologists', { path: "/cardiologists" });
        this.resource('ccprInfoSession', { path: "/infosession" });
        this.resource('ccprPatientPresence', { path: "/patientpresence" });
        this.resource('ccprPresenceOverview', { path: "/presenceoverview" });
        this.resource('ccprNextNutritionalAdvices', { path: "/nextnutritionaladvices" });
    });
    this.resource('ebed', function () {
        this.resource('goBack', { path: '/goback' });
        this.resource('ebedMedications', { path: '/ebedmedications' }, function () {
        });
        this.resource('ebedMedication', { path: '/ebedmedication/:ebed_medication_id' }, function () {
        });
        this.resource('ebedLabResults', { path: '/ebedlabresults' }, function () {
        }); 
        this.resource('ebedLabResult', { path: '/ebedlabresult/:ebed_labresult_id' }, function () {
        });
        this.resource('ebedDietContacts', { path: '/ebeddietcontacts' }, function () {
        });     
        this.resource('ebedDietContact', { path: '/ebeddietcontact/:ebed_dietcontact_id' }, function () {
        });
        this.resource('ebedNutritionBmis', { path: '/ebednutritionbmis' }, function () {
        });         
        this.resource('ebedNutritionBmi', { path: '/ebednutritionbmi/:ebed_nutritionbmi_pkid' }, function () {
        }); 
    });
});
```

Isn't there a nicer way?

Answer (score 1):

[Updated JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/DEmMM/8/)

You can do the same thing in the new router using the `events` property in the router to define actions.  From the [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/):

> If the action is not found on the current controller, it will bubble
>   up to the current route handler. From there, it will bubble up to
>   parent route handlers until it reaches the application route.

In your example you need to define the `goBack` action in the parent of your `animals.dog` and `animals.cat` routes;

```
App.AnimalsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        goBack: function() {
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }
    } });
```

This can be called using the standard `{{action}}` helper from the template.

```
<a href='#' {{action goBack}}>Go Back</a>
```

Comment: I know of the bubbling up of routes, and it would work, but it would not be  a nice solution if you want to reuse your routes, controllers, etc... Some events will be for this part of the router and other events will be for an other part of the router, resulting in some sort of spaghetti route events.

Comment: Do you need to customize the destination of the "go back" button for each route that you use it or is the "go back" always going to take the user to the route they came from? Is this the same functionality as the browser back button?

Comment: Its like the browser back button, but it also needs to have some sort of goBack X. (cfr X times pressed the back button). (If it was just the browser back button I could use history.go(-1))

Comment: what about calling `history.go(-2)` for `goBack 2`, etc?

Comment: That could work, but then I also have the problem that somethimes the url will not be resolved properly. Ex if you add comments to a new post, the url will be something like this (assuming 0 is the id of a new object) /post/0/comments/0 Using the history api will always add another new post and will not get the last created one. If someone can answer this url problem I will accept this answer.

Comment: You shouldn't use an id of 0 as the way to create a new item.  What about using a route like `/post/new` which lets the user create a new post, and then get the id of the newly created post (for this example lets assume it was id `123`) to use when creating the new comment like `/post/123/comments/new` etc. This assumes that the `new` url segment won't conflict with your id scheme.